Retrofit convertor-gson not being recognized
So I'm trying to create an android (Kotlin + Compose) app that makes some API requests. For that, I'm using the following packages/dependenices:
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0") // network calls
implementation("com.squareaup.retrofit2:convertor-gson:2.9.0") // json to object

I've synced the project already, but I can't import the convertor-gson in my project. Specifically, I'm trying to use GsonConverterFactory, but can't use it because it is not recognized.
This is how the import looks like:

Am I doing something wrong?

Your GSON dependency has a typo. It should be:
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.11.0")

Its squareup, not squareaup. And converter, not convertor.
The imports should be:
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory


That was one dumb mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. But even after fixing the typo, syncing the project, still the import is not working.

Please check my updated answer, theres another typo.

I feel Gradle should throw an error or something when the implementation provided doesn't exist.

Yeah, typically gradle does throw an error if you try to sync a rogue dependency with a typo, not sure why it didn't happen for you.
